# How to run cron job in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to **run Cron job** to reindex indexer in Magento 2. Please provide the solution with a code.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following command from CLI form the bin directory:

```
./magento cron:run
```

Answer (score 1):

"One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running"

Goto the cli

> cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/bin/
>
> ### >./magento indexer:reindex

### Output

Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:04
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:13
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:10
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:09

### Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

and then

---

./magento cron:run